# Why is $e^{(x+2x+4x+...+2^{k-1}x)}=e^{((2^k-1)x)}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Could anyone explain me why we have the following equality, $e^{(x+2x+4x+...+2^{k-1}x)}=e^{((2^k-1)x)}$? I don´t see what manipulation we did to get it

Comment: $$1+2+4+\cdots+2^{k-1}=\dfrac{2^k-1}{2-1}$$

Comment: Google "geometric series" for some usefull insights.

Answer (score 1):

It's because $1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + \cdots + 2^{k-1} = 2^k - 1$.

And why is *this* true? Well, maybe an example will convince you why:
\begin{align*}
&\quad\;\; 1 + (1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5) \\
&= 2 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 \\
&= 2^2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 \\
&= 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 \\
&= 2^4 + 2^4 + 2^5 \\
&= 2^5 + 2^5 \\
&= 2^6
\end{align*}
So subtracting $1$ from both sides,
$$
1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 = 2^6 - 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

the sum of the first k terms of a geometric series is
$$\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}r^m=\frac{1-r^k}{1-r}$$
at $r=2$
$$\frac{1-2^k}{1-2}=(2^k-1)$$
so
$$x+2x+4x+8x...=x(2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+....)=x(2^k-1)$$, see [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Answer (score -2):

it is known that $1+a+a^2+...+a^m=(a^{m+1}-1)/(a-1)$. To see this cross multiply and telescope. So $x+2x+...+2^{k-1}x=x(1+2+2^2+...+2^{k-1})=x(2^k-1)$. The result follows.

Comment: If you enclose these in dollar signs, as well as use \frac, you could have a good answer.